# SQLNotificationRequest Application Example or Tutorial

Tags: c#, sql-server, service-broker, sqldependency

After using SQLDepdendency as a queue implementation in one of my projects (now live) and after discovering that it is ineherinitley broken (see http://rusanu.com/2008/01/04/sqldependencyonchange-callback-timing/).

I am desperately looking for alternatives. I am focusing on using SQLNotificationRequest as a replacement, which is what SQLDependency leverages to create a convenient implementation by dynamically creating a Queue and ServiceBroker service at runtime.

I have scoured the internet but i cant seem to find any good examples on SQLNotificationRequest, i have looked here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ht3391b(v=vs.80).aspx, but the code is buggy and doesnt work as expected.

I have also looked at code-project, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18130/Advanced-SQL-SQLNotificationRequest-Functiona but the author maintains that the code is a proof of concept only and also doesnt behave as expected.

Does anyone out there have a good resource they have come across regarding SQLNotificationRequest? A book maybe with a good example or maybe suggestions how to fix the code in link1?

I have run the code but it keeps continuing to check for notifications rather than only fire when changes actually occur the database (changes counter keeps running continously)

[image]

Comment: What is it that you actually need to support here? Would it be possible, for example, for code to *announce* changes that have been made? There are a lot of very simple to use pub/sub APIs that can be used for message delivery, etc

Comment: Im basically using a sql table that acts as queue and am using the SQLDependency to watch for changes to the table. From their i get the table contents and process the queue. Thing is ive already built my system around this implementation and would prefer to try and fix the problem...but if needed i will have to create a different queueing system.

Comment: I'm not necessarily saying "change the queue" - I'm only talking about the notification process. Frankly, I've never been satisfied that SQL notifications work for real-world scenarios.

Comment: You can try SqlDependencyEx - i tried it and pretty good. More info can be found here. https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener